# WPF TextBox with SpellCheck.IsEnabled="True" - No SpellChecking happening?

Tags: .net, wpf, spell-checking

I just wanted to play around with WPF SpellCheck a little, but although the Attached Property is set, there's no underlining of whatever I type.

```
SpellCheck.IsEnabled="True"
```

If I remember correctly, SpellCheck is supposed to add Menu Items to my ContextMenu as well, isn't it? That doesn't happen either...

BTW, my machine is running .Net4.

Do I have to enable this globally somewhere? All tutorials and so forth just mention setting SpellCheck.IsEnabled gets you going...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Make sure the required language pack is installed. refer this post for more info. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wpf/thread/c4a62da5-9a7d-4e1d-bcbc-12945046fc42

Comment: Thanks, I just found out that it works when I add Language="en-US" to the Tag. That being said we will have to get the language pack! Thanks for your swift response =)